# How can I create a loop to create a new variable for different dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to know how to create a loop to create the same new variable for 7 different dataframes. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
m1_02 <- m1_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m2_02 <- m2_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m3_02 <- m3_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m3_02a <- m3_02a %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m6a2_02 <- m6a2_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m6b1_02 <- m6b1_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
m6b2_02 <- m6b2_02 %>% mutate(hhid = xa*10^5 + hoso)
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could create a loop that would create the `hhid` variable in the respective dataframes without having to use the `mutate` function one by one.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you're doing the same thing to multiple frames, it's likely better to work with a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) instead of keeping them as separate objects.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to load the datasets into a `list` and then perform the operation at once and store the output in a `list` instead of creating more objects in the global env

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "^m.*\\d+_\\d+$")) %>%
    map(~ .x %>%
            mutate(hhid = xa * 10^5 + hoso))
```

If we need to update the original object, use `list2env`on the output `list`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```